# CURL PHP couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$ch = curl_init("http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($html);
```

в переменную html вообще не записывается ничего var_dump - bool(false), что это может быть ?

Comment: У cURL есть функции [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-errno.php), [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php), а также [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php). Чем гадать, лучше посмотрите, что они вам сообщат.

Comment: couldn't connect to host

Comment: А какой ресурс вы хотите открыть через CURL ?

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, false);
```

вот это еще добавить надо, мне помогло

Answer (score 0):

`curl_exec()` возвращает `false` при неудаче: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues

- проверяйте на ошибки с помощью [`curl_errno()`](http:// php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-errno.php) (**до** того как закроете, вызвав curl_close)
- логируйте этот код и инфо об ошибке с помощью [`curl_error()`](http:// php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php) (**до** того как закроете, вызвав curl_close)
- делайте выводы и соответствующие изменения :)

из примера в документации:

```
<?php
// Создаем дескриптор curl к несуществующему адресу
$ch = curl_init('http://404.php.net/');

// Запускаем
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

// Проверяем наличие ошибки
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Закрываем дескриптор
curl_close($ch);
?>
```